# how cookie and session work in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

couple of day's ago I asked my friend about the session of my website and how make it work correctly and he gave me this code right here...

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function () {
    /*$("a").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("hideFocus", "true");
    });*/
    jQuery.cookie = function (name, value, options) {
        if (typeof value != 'undefined') {
            options = options || {};
            if (value === null) {
                value = '';
                options.expires = -1;
            }
            var expires = '';
            if (options.expires && (typeof options.expires == 'number' || options.expires.toUTCString)) {
                var date;
                if (typeof options.expires == 'number') {
                    date = new Date();
                    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (options.expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                } else {
                    date = options.expires;
                }
                expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString();
            }
            var path = options.path ? '; path=' + (options.path) : '';
            var domain = options.domain ? '; domain=' + (options.domain) : '';
            var secure = options.secure ? '; secure' : '';
            document.cookie = [name, '=', encodeURIComponent(value), expires, path, domain, secure].join('');
        } else {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
    };
```

I notice the expire in the code but i don't know what  exactly it is doing in the program?
I just want someone simply explain the codes above if it's possible.
thanks.

Comment: So ask your friend then? SO isn't a support for every piece of code you've found somewhere

Comment: i would if i could reach him!!!

Comment: Sharif: well, anyway - it's a programmers community. You need to understand your code at least somehow.

Comment: did you figure that out by yourself!!!

Comment: I learned how to program, yep. I spent **A LOT** of time doing that. Have you?

Comment: dude you've got no idea?

Comment: @NimaSharify You need to have some understanding of the code you supply. As it stands it's not even a programming problem and no one will benefit from this question but you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie is a small piece of data sent from a website and stored in a user's web browser while a user is browsing a website.

There are some parameters which can regulate the behavior of cookie in a browser

1. Name of the cookie
2. Value of the cookie
3. The expiry of the cookie (using Greenwich Mean Time)
4. The path the cookie is good for
5. The domain the cookie is good for
6. The need for a secure connection to use the cookie.

In combination of sessions of a server side language like PHP they can be used to store state of the user.Like is user logged in or out ,privileges etc.

The above code sets or gets the value of cookie stored in users browser.

Reference :

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)